# What is wrong with my create table SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 management studio to execute the following SQL statements, and here is the related error message from SQL Server management studio. Any ideas what is wrong?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create TABLE [dbo].[BatchStatus](
    [BatchID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [PK_BatchStatus_ID],
    [BatchStatus] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_BatchStatus_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [BatchID] ASC
    )WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO



Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table
expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the 
previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the "PK_BatchStatus_ID" constraint twice - once on the line where you define the BatchID field, once at the end of the table definition.

You can **EITHER** define your constraint "inline" with the column:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BatchStatus]
    ([BatchID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT [PK_BatchStatus_ID] PRIMARY KEY,
    [BatchStatus] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

or then you can define it **AFTER** all the columns of the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BatchStatus]
    ([BatchID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [BatchStatus] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_BatchStatus_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [BatchID] ASC
    )WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

but you can't have both (partially)

Marc

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Create TABLE [dbo].[BatchStatus](
    [BatchID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [BatchStatus] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_BatchStatus_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [BatchID] ASC
    )WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Your SQL statement is the same as mine? Confused... :-)

Comment: It's not. He removed CONSTRAINT [PK_BatchStatus_ID] after the BatchID definition.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works! But I am so confused, we are not allowing constraints after column definition? I just copy some workable SQL statement from my legacy SQL Server version (2005) projects. Is it a new restriction or grammar in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: It's from SQL Server version (2005) but you should look at yours database compatibility setting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you really wanted. A constraint specifying the default value

```
Create TABLE [dbo].[BatchStatus](
    [BatchID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_BatchStatus_ID] DEFAULT((0)),
    [BatchStatus] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_BatchStatus_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [BatchID] ASC
    ) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```